# UPDATE only if COUNT from another table is not zero

Tags: mysql, update, count

I update a table by counting the FK from another table as

```
UPDATE table1 
SET number = number +
(
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 
WHERE  table1.id=table2.id
)
```

`table1` is a big table, and I want to make the `UPDATE` only if `COUNT` has found something. In other words, I do not want to make the `UPDATE` for `number=0`.

Answer (score 7):

Derive a table of counts by `id` from `table2`, join the results to `table1` and use that join in the UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE
  table1 AS t1
  INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        id,
        COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM
        table2
      GROUP BY
        id
    ) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
SET
  t1.number = t1.number + t2.cnt
;
```

The above statement will affect only the `table1` rows that have matches in `table2`.

Answer (score 2):

Add `where exists` to it:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET number = number +
(
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 
WHERE  table1.id=table2.id
)
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM table2
WHERE  table1.id=table2.id
)
```